ASP.NET Core 6 : HttpContext.Request.Body stream cant go higher than 4096
I'm writing an ASP.NET Core 6 program which receives many files and writes them to a SQLite database.
I'm using the following code on the client to send the file:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage() 
                  {
                      Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                      RequestUri = new Uri(server.serverBase + "/api/snapshot/UploadFile"),
                  };

using (FileStream filestream = File.Open(file.getFilePath(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) 
{
        var length = filestream.Length.ToString();

        var streamContent = new StreamContent(filestream, 16384);
        streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length);

        request.Content = streamContent;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        //Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}

And the following code on the server to receive the stream:
[HttpPost("UploadFile")]
[RequestSizeLimit(100000000000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024; //1 MB chunk size

    using (Stream stream = HttpContext.Request.Body) 
    {
        var buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;
        int chunkNumber = 0;
        long totalNumBytes = 0;
        int progress = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bytesRead);
            await ProcessChunk(buffer, bytesRead, chunkNumber, totalNumBytes);
            chunkNumber++;
        }
    }

    return Ok("File uploaded and chunked successfully.");
}

However, despite the buffer size being 1048576 bytes, the debug output is always 4096, I.E, I'm only reading 4096 bytes per each "chunk" of the stream.
How can I increase the buffer size beyond 4096 bytes?
My end goal is to take each "chunk" and store it into a database as blob, most of the files being sent are ~3KB, so I was intending to change each "chunk" size so 1KB so less rows are used per each file chunk.
I've tried:

Changing the Kestrel limits
"enableBuffering" on the request object
Using a MemoryStream

I was expecting the stream buffer of HttpContext.Request.Body to increase beyond 4096 bytes but it seems I can't get it go above that.

When using Kestrel you should be able to set options when setting it up
builder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                });

which I presume from what you've tried you already did.
I notice you added in a larger (100000000000) than recommended upper limit, have you tried what is recommended in the documentation
 [RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]

or indeed
 [DisableRequestSizeLimit]

I came across this when looking into this and thought it might be of interest for completeness
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1000 * 1024 * 1024)]


This did not work sorry, I'm using Kestral (not IIS). I tried with:
builder.Services.Configure(options =>
{
options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
But that didn't work.
From my research the default for this setting you've mentioned is 28.6MB, yet I'm only seeing 4096 per chunk in the HttpContext.Request.Body buffer?

fair point, I read that too fast, adjusted answer accordingly.

Believe I have found the problem. see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30545.
when I remove "app.UseHttpsRedirection();" and I try sending the file via http and not https the buffer size is not limited to 4096 bytes.
Not sure how I can fix it with SSL turned on.

interesting, looks like the underlying issue, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49000, was merged in 2021 just before .NET core 6.  Would updating to .NET core 8 be an option for you?  Worth adding .NET 6 is out of support in two months.  I didn't verify but that fix might not be included in 6 but be in 8

I tried switching the product to .net 8 and the problem still remains. Not sure why as github implies it's fixed now...

and just to double check, you updated both client and server to .NET 8?  if it was this issue it is fixed in .NET 8 for sure.  So might have to consider something else if it is still there
